# Argument passed must be an instance of longtext, string given - doctrin2 symfony

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm

I have problem with polluting mySQL field defined as text field with data received as a result of `serialize() php` command. I am using `symfony2` with `doctrine annotations`.

My service code:

```
$oe = serialize($object);
$log->setObject(serialize($object));
```

and entity:

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $object;
```

The error that I get is following:

```
Symfony
Search on Symfony website
Exception detected!
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\Log::setObject() must be an instance of longtext, string given, called in C:\wamp\www\symfony_learn\src\AppBundle\Service\loggerService.php on line 22 and defined
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException
```

It seems that there is mismatch of data types but I don't quite understand it as one data type is string and second is text and thus to my mind the conversion should take place automatically. I know that I can do it with mySQL cast but I wonder with `symfony2` and `doctrine2` provides any tools to deal with such situation?

Comment: If somebody want to down vote this question it would be kind to provide clues what do you find wrong or unclear in it. I have searched threw web and can't find answer.

Comment: what does the setObject look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that using:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

resulted in:

```
  public function setObject(\longtext $object)
    {
        $this->object = $object;

        return $this;
    }
```

Removing `\longtext` from `setObject()` solved my problem.

In addtion I have changed my field type into "object" as adviced by http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html

Answer (score 1):

try  using  mySql CAST:

```
CAST(yourVarchar as LONGTEXT)
```

Comment: Thanks for clue. This would probably work and I will implement it if no other solution is found but I am rather looking for solution using symfony2 and doctrine.